# 2 flat rates based on category

Tags: magento2, magento-1, shipping, table-rates, flat

I have a magento shop that will be selling both frozen and non-frozen foods. I'm trying to figure out how to set two straight flat shipping prices. One for each.

As well as this, i need to set it so if orders are over a certain amoutn shippping is free, however i'm aware that this is done through the table shipping settings.

I've looked into different possible modules to help with this, but i can't seem to find anything to fit what i'm looking for. They all seem to relate to weight for the most part instead of category. Does anyone have any ideas or can point me in the right direction to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

As always with shipping, just have a look whether web shop apps has something. I think "PRODUCT MATRIX" should do what you need. Unfortunately it is not free at all.